# ¿Por qué con la condición WHERE NOT EXISTS se hace la inserción varias veces en lugar de sólo una?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con datos dentro de ella. Específicamente la tabla cuenta con 336 filas de información y estoy ejecutando la siguiente *query*:

```sql
INSERT INTO lista(num_empleado,nombre) SELECT 1850,'Jorge' FROM lista WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM lista WHERE num_empleado = 1850 AND nombre = 'Jorge');
```

Aquí la estructura general de la tabla:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `lista` (
  `id` int(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `num_empleado` int(80) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4; 

ALTER TABLE `lista`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `lista`
  MODIFY `id` int(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4485;
```

Aquí la representación gráfica:

| id | num_empleado | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1850 | Jorge |
| 02 | 1104 | Luis |
| 03 | 1120 | María |

Lo que busco lograr con lo anterior es que cualquier inserción que se intente hacer dentro de la tabla no se efectúe si los datos que se están intentando insertar ya existen en la tabla. El problema es que al momento de realizarse una inserción, lo ideal sería que se hiciera una sola vez, pero en lugar de eso se realiza 336 veces (la misma cantidad de filas existentes en la tabla). ¿Por qué sucede esto? Sé que probablemente mi *query esté* mal planteada, pero no logró descifrar cómo debería corregirla para que la inserción se efectúe una sola vez.

Comment: Esto se hace poniendo un CONSTRAINT UNIQUE sobre el campo o campos que deban ser únicos.

Comment: @Jorge Duran, porqué el `num_empleado` no es un valor único ???

Comment: Porque ```num_empleado``` se puede repetir en la tabla. Ese número se puede volver a reasignar a otra persona. Realmente lo que quiero evitar es que se capture dos o más veces la misma información porque es un error que puede suceder.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO lista(num_empleado,nombre) 
SELECT 1850,'Jorge' FROM lista 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM lista WHERE num_empleado = 1850 AND nombre = 'Jorge');
```

Inserta en lista, columnas num_empleado, nombre
Los datos 1850, 'Jorge' de lista
Donde no exista 
(Selecciona 1 de toda lista donde num_empleado = 1850 y nombre = 'Jorge')

Acá, el SELECT 1, esta tomando 1 registro, que corresponde al de Jorge 1850, pero **POR CADA LINEA DE TODA LA TABLA** !!!

Tomando esta pag. como referencia:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-does-it-mean-by-select-1-from-mysql-table

> La declaración "SELECT 1" de cualquier nombre de tabla significa que solo devuelve 1. Por ejemplo, si una tabla tiene 4 registros, **devolverá 1 cuatro veces.**

Ahora, si quisieras realizar la inserción 1 vez, no necesitas el WHERE, solo asignar una llave al num_empleado, que me imagino debiese ser unico.

Comment: ¿Cómo se adaptaría la query para realizar la inserción una sola vez?

Comment: Primero que nada, comparte la estructura de tu tabla. Segundo, y como mencioné antes, solo basta con el INSERT INTO, sin el WHERE.

Comment: Pero quitando "WHERE", no habría criterio para evitar que no se puedan insertar duplicados. Ya actualicé mi pregunta con la estructura de la tabla